# Interdependent android projects

Tags: android, projects

I was wondering if its possible to reference one android project from another android project.  I have two projects, test1 and test2.  I have added test2 in the project properties of test1 under the projects tab.  Unfortunately it keeps throwing a NoClassDefFoundError.  Also, would the second android project (test2) be installed as a separate apk on the phone or would it be part of the encapsulating android project (test1) ?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just be aware that if test2 contains resources, these will not automatically be packaged in a non-android project and the R file will not be auto-generated.

I suggest that you look at release 6 of the [SDK tools](http://developer.android.com/sdk/tools-notes.html) (released this week), they now support library projects.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply.  Just found out about the library.  They released it just in time :)

Answer (score 0):

You may also extract the common functionality into the third project and reference it. This should be a regular Java project not the Android project. So it will produce jar that you can reference.